# Disable page reloads in test-cafe framework using single page apps

Tags: angular, testing, single-page-application, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have a problem in test-cafe with angular, for each test case the browser reloads which takes much time,
I want to disable the page reload for each test, anyone has any idea?, if this solution not implemented yet by test-cafe developers for SPA, does anyone know when this issue could be fixed?.

Answer (score 1):

TestCafe has the unpublished `Disable page reloads` feature. See more information [here](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/3945#issuecomment-507211138). You can try to use it, but there are a few limitation for it (concurrency and quarantine modes don't work, the test name in service panel is not updated, etc.)